# Zoom function not working in d3 library (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

In html, the SVG image is specified via the  tag. Using the d3 library, I'm trying to write a script that should zoom svg. I don't understand how to access the svg image itself through the select library method.

html

```
<div id="container" style="width: 1600px; height: 1200px; border:1px solid black;">
        <object class="svg-image" type="image/svg+xml" data="./grf_195.svg"></object>
    </div>
    <script src="./package/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
```

javascript

```
let zoom = d3.zoom().on('zoom', handleZoom);
    
function handleZoom(e) {
    d3.select('.svg-image').attr('transform', e.transform);
}
  
function initZoom() {
    d3.select('.svg-image').call(zoom);
}
initZoom();
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, but post the actual code

Answer (score 0):

#### Wait until the `<object>` is fully loaded

```js
let zoom = d3.zoom().on('zoom', handleZoom);

function handleZoom(e) {
    d3.select(this.contentDocument.documentElement)
        .attr('transform', e.transform);
}

function initZoom() {
    d3.select('.svg-image').node().addEventListener('load', function() {
        d3.select(this.contentDocument.documentElement).call(zoom);
    });
}

initZoom();
```

We added a `load` event listener to the `<object>` element that contains the `SVG image`. Once the `SVG document` has loaded, we can access it via `this.contentDocument.documentElement`, and then call the zoom behavior on it.

Comment: Thanks very much! Sorry for the stupid question, but what should I substitute for the place of this.content Document.documentElement ?

Comment: `this.contentDocument.documentElement` is referring to the root element of the document that is loaded inside an `<iframe>` or `<object>`.